# Resigning as Moderator from the Workplace

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have made the easy decision of stepping down.

Some of you will ask or want to know why, and the reason is simple:  it isn't fun anymore, and I no longer see any personal benefit in being a Moderator.

So long, and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: But why??  Oh, you said so.  Fair enough - it's a time consuming and mostly thankless task.  Thanks for everything you've done for the community - you held the reins when no one else did...

Comment: Many thanks to you and your dolphin brethren.

Comment: I always feel awkward upvoting resignation posts - my upvote simply means "Your absence will be noticed/you'll be missed." I hope the time you reclaim by retiring from mod duties will be filled with fun or at least free of drama :)

Comment: What was the personal benefit that you initially received, and which you no longer see?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That is a fair question good sir, that I am going to pass on answering.  ;-}

Comment: @Neo I have to congratulate you on a brilliant answer to that query

Comment: Thank you for everything Neo! It'll be a shame to lose you but your reason for moving on is a perfectly understandable one. If this starts feeling like a chore then it makes sense to pull back. Hope we'll continue to see you on the site of course!

Comment: Can I make a poor reference? I guess now you can free your mind.

Comment: @Clockwork Genius.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You did a great job.  Your resignation is TWP's loss.

As snow said, it is a thankless job, but let me offer my thanks to you for being a cool head, voice of reason, and port in the storm.  You led by example, and have provided an excellent one which should be the benchmark of anyone who succeeds you.

Comment: Thanks for saying that.  I am hopeful you get a couple new motivated moderators soon.

Comment: @Neo I mean it.  I know that I, for one, can be a handful.  So, if a jerk like me thinks you did a good job, it's high praise indeed ;)

Comment: @Neo I didn’t get an epithet of this standard, so that must be a mark of how highly you’re regarded.

Comment: @Snow I was a jerk to you too.  Sorry for the belated comment.  ;)

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter Nope, you're cool - you held us to a higher standard than we held ourselves.  You also have made a huge contribution to this community and the people who have asked for advice.

Comment: @Snow I don't even remember you resigning, if I didn't mention it then, I'll thank you now. I recall that you returned to hold the fort when everyone was running for the door a while back. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for your contributions to the site!

When it's no longer fun, it makes a lot of sense to re-evaluate.

Comment: This might be a good time for you to consider running as Moderator ;-}

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a concrete reason. Thanks for all your work moderating.