# 2021 Moderator Election will start on Monday (March 8)

Tags: discussion, election

As many of you know, one of our moderators recently [decided to move on](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/resigning-as-moderator-from-the-workplace?cb=1) so our moderation team is down to two. To make sure our site has the coverage it needs, we've asked the Community Team to start up the election process. Our 2021 moderator election is set to start **this Monday, March 8th** with the question collection process. Nominations will open the week after with the election itself starting the week after that. [The election page is already visible](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/8) if you'd like to review the timeline.

**Two moderator positions will be available.** While our day to day tasks were manageable, having an extra person around will help us have an increased presence throughout the day and consistent coverage throughout the year. We also want to make sure that we keep the average workload down so that moderation duties don't start to feel like a chore and people can be flexible with the amount of time they put in.

We encourage anyone thinking of stepping up to already take a look at [What's it like being a Workplace Moderator?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5938/whats-it-like-being-a-workplace-moderator) and [What are the day-to-day activities of Moderators?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/what-are-the-day-to-day-activities-of-moderators) to get a sense of what moderation is about. You can also check the [questionnaires of previous elections.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Belection%5D%20questionnaire%20is%3Aq)

If you have any additional questions or even doubts on whether to nominate yourself feel free to ask about that here or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120709/2021-the-workplace-moderator-election-chat).

Comment: I do want to take the opportunity to thank you again, Neo, for all the time and energy you've put in over the years and for your offer to stick around until after the election. I hope our new moderators will live up to your example. :)

Comment: Thanks for everything @Neo, specially for always being supportive and patient. Godspeed wherever you go Sir :)

Comment: I nominate Neo for the job

Comment: @Kilisi Bwah ha ha ha...maybe I will once again down the line...like years down the line.

Comment: I second the nomination of Neo